# Buttons losing functionality when positioned over background image

Tags: html, css

I am having the weirdest problem: I am working on a portfolio page with images that should link to the various projects. There are 6 of these in total. Each of the images has a button that should live on top of it. When the button is hovered on by the user, it changes color, the cursor changes, and a popup with a short description of the project opens. When the button is clicked, there is an event listener that redirects to the project's page.

The problem is that in 2 out of the 6 instances, the moment I position the buttons inside the image, the buttons lose all functionality (including the event listener). As far as I can tell the code governing these 2 instances is the same as the other 4 where there is no such problem.

code where it doesn't work:
HTML:

```
  <div class="container" id="linkTwo">
    <img src="assets/images/bonez2.jpg" alt="bonez" style="width:200px; height:200px;" class="linkpic" >
    <div class="btn1"id="btn1">Bone's Beatz<span id="bonezPop"> */some text that pops up/* </span></div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
#linkTwo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 230px;
}
#linkTwo #btn1:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
#btn1 {
  position: absolute;
  left:20px;
  padding-left: 23px;
  padding-right: 23px;
}
#btn1 #bonezPop {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #883043;
  color: #aa9e9e;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 2px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
#btn1:hover #bonezPop {
  visibility: visible;
}
.container #btn1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 53px;
  padding-right: 53px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

code that DOES work:
HTML:

```
 <div class="container" id="linkFive">
  <img src="assets/images/weather.jpg" alt="weather app" style="width:200px;height:200px;"  class="linkpic">
  <div class="btn3" id="btn3">Weather App<span id="weatherPop"> */some text that pops up */</span></div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
#linkFive {
  position: absolute;
  top:320px;
}
#btn3 #weatherPop {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #883043;
  color: #aa9e9e;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 2px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
#btn3:hover #weatherPop {
  visibility: visible;
}

#btn3 {
  padding-left: 53px;
  padding-right: 53px;
}
.container .btn3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.container .btn3:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
```

I realize this whole thing would have been done much more easily with WordPress or some such, but this is a class assignment that requires I do this with code.

Thanks!

[Short gif of how the problem looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwHui.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. It was a different CSS rule that was for some reason breaking it:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}
```

commenting this out solved the problem.